# Screwy social network wall code logic

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The goal:

pull from members walls
    - if two friends share the same churchMember relationship, show streams

pull following tables:

- friends
- wallPosts
- users
- churchMembers

table structures:

friends table:

```
- id, node1id, node2id
```

wallPosts:

```
- entryData
- postingUserId
```

users:

```
- userpid
- username
- firstname
- lastname
```

church members:

```
- churchid
- userid
```

How would I put the above requirements into code?

Update:

select all rows that have the same churchId as the one that the user logged in is connected with `$churchId = '1';`

```
SELECT * FROM churchMembers WHERE  cMchurchId = $churchId
if $row-cMchurchId == $churchId
    SELECT * FROM churchMembers, users WHERE churchMembers.cMuserId = users.userid
```

Comment: you tagged it codeigniter, do you have any code to show us to see what you have attempted?

Comment: Okay. I updated it. I was just messing around. That's a little pseudo-code nothing real. I think I got it in the first sql statement, but i need to be able to pull the data from the users table that is associated with the church relation that matches cMchurchId = $churchId. cMuserId is what identifies the user with the churchMember row. and I also need to show all rows from wallPosts if cMchurchId = $churchId equates to true for any user. It's kind of complicated as you can tell.

Comment: do you know about joins? http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: Yeah I do. This is too complicated for me to figure out though

Comment: could I use a left join with these requirements?

Comment: too give you a good answer, can we assume, that userid on church_members is a foreign key to userpid on the users table? and postingUserId on wallPosts is a foreign Key to that same userpid? and how do friends and users relate? is the friend-id the userid?

Comment: friends relate in the friends table. node1id is my id and node2id is my friends id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started:

```
$friendId = 5;

$sql = "select w.entryData from wallposts w
        inner join church_members cm 
          on cm.userid = w.postingUserId
        where cm.churchid = 
          (SELECT churchid from church_members where userId='" + $friendId + "'");
```

ok, if those are userid's in the friends table, you can go like this:

```
select w.entryData from friends f
inner join church_members cm on f.node2id = cm.userid  //<--friends church
inner join church_members cm2 on f.node1id = cm2.userid //<-- my church
inner join wallposts w on w.postingUserId = f.node2Id //<-- grab the friends wallposts
inner join users u on f.node2id = u.userpid //<-- grab the user data
where cm2.church_id = cm.church_id //<-- they got's to be the same :)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to this lol, so for the `on cm.node2id=users.userpid` I need to add INNER JOIN or add it to the where?